# Code using new IDE

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int max = 0;

    cout << "enter number: ";
    cin >> number;

    while (number !=0);
    {
        if ((number % 10) > max)) //rem of 10 {


            max = (number % 10);
        }
        number /= 10
    }
    cout << "larggest" << max
    return 0;
```

(using codeblock IDE and getting error)

> 15 error: expected ';' before ')' token
>   21 error: expected ';' before '}'
>   23 error: expected ';' before 'return'
>            expected '}' at end of input

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In line 15 you added an extra `)` at the end. It should be:

```
if ((number % 10) > max)
```

In line 20 you forgot a `;` at the end. It should be:

```
number /= 10;
```

In line 22 you forgot another `;`. It should be:

```
cout << "larggest" << max;
```

You also forgot to add a `}` at the end to finish main().

In addition to that, you added a `;` on line 13:

```
while (number !=0);
```

You probably meant it without the `;` because otherwise it checks if `number !=0` then does nothing, checks if `number !=0`, does nothing and loops infinitely.

Finally, you spelt largest wrong. ;)

Comment: "Look! I have one job on this lousy ship, it's *stupid*, but I'm gonna do it! Okay?" (c) Galaxy Quest

Answer (score 1):

```
while (number !=0);
```

There's an extra semicolon there

```
number /= 10
```

And there isn't one there.

```
if ((number % 10) > max))
```

And you've got mis-matched parenthesis there.

```
cout << "larggest" << max
```

Missing semicolon ...

And there's no `}` at the end to close the `main()` function.

The error messages are telling you you have syntax problems.

**Edit:** In editing the question to make it readable I inadvertently fixed another issue. I've changed the OP's code back and ...

```
if ((number % 10) > max)) //rem of 10 {
```

You commented out the opening `{`

Comment: Im getting less errors..but for if ((number % 10) > max)) //rem of 10 Im getting "expected primary-expression before ')' token///expected ';' before 'return'

Comment: That's because you are commenting out the first { in that line and therefore you have a } that doesn't match. Your code has been edited above, but check my answer to be sure.

Comment: Yeah. my bad - my initial edit to make it readable fixed one of the problems. I've reverted that particular issue

Comment: That being said, this really has nothing to do with an IDE. This is basic syntax, and it's kinda important to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

- You have a semicolon after your while loop. Delete that semi-colon.
- Line 15, where you have the following:

  `if ((number % 10) > max)) //rem of 10 {`

That's causing a syntax error in your if since the first { is being commented out.

- `cout << "larggest" << max 23. return 0`
  You shouldn't have a dot after "max 23" there.
- `number /= 10`
  Needs a semicolon.